# PHP fails to parse large post variable

Tags: post, apache2, php-5.3, php

I'm trying to pass a rather large post request to php, and when I var_dump $_POST array, one,  the most large, variable is missing. (Actually that's base64 encoded binary upload as part of a post request)

Funny thing, that on my development PC exactly same request is parsed correctly, without any missing variables.

I checked out contents of php://input on server and development PC and they are exactly the same, md5 matches. Yet development PC recognizes all variables, and server misses one.
I tried changing many different options in php.ini, and got zero effect.

Maybe someone will point me to the right one.
Here is my php://input (~5 megabytes) http://www.mediafire.com/?lp0uox53vhr35df

Comment: Your probably hitting the max_post_size that's been set in the .ini

Comment: Nope, it's already 220M. And if that would be it, php://input would not contain entire information.

Comment: I'd expect the memory limit being ok - but have you checked to make sure it's set high enough to also process the size? I'd be surprised if it wasn't though.

Comment: 128M should be pretty okay for the task of parsing 5 mb input, right? I can double-check value in runtime, or increase it to test things.

Comment: Having the limit at 128mb will limit the max post to 128mb, but it should of course be plenty to handle a 5mb post.

Comment: Does the server use suhosin extension?

Comment: @dqhendricks not using browser at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the server is blocking it because of Suhosin extension.

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_value_length

> suhosin.post.max_value_length
>
> Type: Integer Default: 65000 Defines the maximum length of a variable
>   that is registered through a POST request.

This will have to be changed in the php.ini.

Keep in mind that this is different than the Suhosin patch which is common on alot of shared hosts.  I don't know if the patch would cause this problem.

Comment: suhosin.post.max_value_length = 250000000
Unfortuantely I have already tried that. Maybe format is not right, I'll check this value in runtime about 7 hours later.

Comment: It worked together with suhosin.request.max_value_length. I will mark your answer as correct, it was the closest one.